# Is there a way to have a text file installed along with an android program?

Tags: android

I would like to have text files installed on an android device when they use the apk file and install the app. Ideally, I would like to create a folder structure that gets created as well but haven't been able to find a way to do any of this, I need these text files to use inside of the program. This is my first post so if I did anything wrong let me know, and if you need more specific information I will be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the file in the `assets` folder in your `app` folder and it will be copied to the device along with the installation files.

And then you can access the file this way:

```
AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
InputStream myInputStream = am.open("default_book.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your text files inside of the res folder and use it within your program